# Is RequireJS optimization only applicable to scripts that reside on the same server?

Tags: requirejs, r.js, requirejs-optimizer

About half of the scripts that I use are on CDN and the other half are on the same server as the app. I don't know what to optimize in this case. Can somebody suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [r.js optimizer cannot load network resources](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty) so you don't even have much choice. In your build profile you'll need to replace the path mappings with `"empty:"`, as per the example:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js",
    paths: {
        jquery: "empty:"
    }
})
```

This way both development and minified version of your application will use the CDN version of `jquery` dependency.